# sigwait() does not work in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

I'm trying to write a multithreaded program which one thread (variable thread in below) is responsible to any asynchronous signals that might be set to this process.

I am facing thread that uses sigwait() but does not react to any signals have been sent to process. (like SIGUSR1 in below).

```
static void * signal_thread(void *arg = nullptr)
{
    int sig = -1;
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigfillset(&sigset);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
    while(1)
    {
       int s = sigwait(&sigset, &sig);
       if(s == 0)
          printf("SIG %d recieved!...\n", sig);
       usleep(20);
    }
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t signalset;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &signal_thread, nullptr);
    sigfillset(&signalset);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signalset, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
       raise(SIGUSR1);
       usleep(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Signals and threads are allergic to each other.   You either need to tippy-toe or isolate.  Better the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is concerned to two issues:

First, call of raise in main sent signal only to main thread not whole process.

Secondly, std::cout should be used instead of printf in signal_thread.

Answer (score 0):

[`raise(sig)` is the equivalent of calling `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), sig)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/raise.html).

Since the `main` thread `raise()`s the signal, the SIGUSR1 will be generated for that thread and not for any other.  Thus, your `signal_thread` will be unable to `sigwait()` for the USR1, which will be held pending for the thread that generated it.